# how to respond an error to payments_get_items method in the credit callback

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-credits

Anybody know how to respond an error to the payments_get_items method?

for the payments_status_update method we can send a "canceled" status, but no error message is documented (as I konw) for the payments_get_items method

For example... there is an item any user can buy, but with a limited quantity global to the game; an user UI was loaded when there are items left so he can send an order, but when I was sending back the item description I detect that there aren't any item left: I don't want to send the description now and then give a "canceled" message in the following communication

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's an official method - one option would be to 'hack' around their system by responding with a "fake" item which costs 0 currency and informs the player that the item is no longer available.